# How do I convert my Arraylist to JSON and Post it to MySQL?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I've been trying for a while now to convert all my phone numbers in my phone to JSON and upload them in one post to a mysql db, can you help? I'm focusing on the Android side of things right now - php will be later.

So, I make an arraylist of all my numbers - when you click the `buttonCheck` button you can see them all in logcat, but after all I've read the methods `size` and `length` are still not recognised by my `alContacts` array. I believe that's the track I should be taking to convert to JSON (?). Here's my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // this is the php file name where to select from the database, the user's phone number
    private static final String CHECKPHONENUMBER_URL = "http://www.example.com/myfile.php";

    //we are posting phoneNo, which in PHP is phonenumber
    public static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";

    //alContacts is a list of all the phone numbers
    public static final ArrayList<String> alContacts = new ArrayList<String>();

    Button buttonCheck;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);

        //get the names and phone numbers of all contacts in phone book
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {


                String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        alContacts.add(phoneNo);
                       // break;
                    }
                    pCur.close();

                }
            }
        }

        buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("Print the contacts array : ");
                System.out.println(alContacts);

                 CheckifUserisContact();
            }
        });

    }


// send the numbers in one POST to the mySql db with Volley

    private void CheckifUserisContact() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CHECKPHONENUMBER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if (response.equals("failure")) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "succeeded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }) {

            //********* HAVING TROUBLE HERE *******************

          //  JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
          //  jsonObject.put("alContacts",jsonArray);
            //for(int i=0;i<=alContacts.size;i++){}

            //*****************************************************

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER, jsonArray.toString());
                return params;

            }

        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
//********* HAVING TROUBLE HERE *******************

try {
        JSONObject dataToSend = new JSONObject();

        // contacts
        JSONArray jsonArrayContacts = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < alContacts.size(); i++)
        {
            // contact
            JSONObject jsonObjectContact = new JSONObject();
            jsonObjectContact.put("phone_number", alContacts.get(i));

            // Add contact jsonObject to contacts jsonArray
            jsonArrayContacts.put(jsonObjectContact);
        }

        // Add contacts jsonArray to jsonObject
        dataToSend.put("contacts", jsonArrayContacts);

        Log.d("JSON", "JSON: " + dataToSend.toString());

    } catch (final JSONException e) {
        Log.e("FAILED", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

//*****************************************************
```

**Here is the output JSON format:**

```
    {
        "contacts":[
        {
            "phone_number":"019114-123456"
        },
        {
            "phone_number":"016174-123456"
        },
        {
            "phone_number":"012104-123456"
        }]
    }
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: In fact I think your block of code should be in my 'public void onResponse' part, rather than the 'Response.ErrorListener'. Works great now, thanks !

Comment: My pleasure  :).... Best practice is to build the JSON before making a string/JSONObject request. In your onResponse you will get the response JSON from server if  successfully your conatct JSON data send to server,